# Stackoverflow should have Latex Syntax Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, latex

As i just asked a LaTex-question on SO, i noticed that there is no correct Syntax-highlighting for Latex-Code in a codeblock. This makes it hard to read the code.

Would it be possible to add the Latex-Syntax to the codeblocks?

Comment: Just curious, why the minus one?

Comment: Yeah. Downvoting without leaving a comment = great!

Comment: never mind downvotes here on Meta, they are used as an expression of disagreement more than a judgement on the quality of the question. ... +1. I don't use Latex myself, but adding highlighting for that popular a language sounds like a reasonable request.

Comment: @Pekka: I'm a big latex user (and defender) myself, but I'm not sure that it constitutes a "popular" language. Nor is there anything like a common standard for highlighting latex. I mean, I'm an auctex user, but there are at least two other modes just in emacs.

Comment: Aside to ifischer: do you want more rep?  You DO?  Manually deassociate and reassociate your Meta and SO accounts from the "accounts" tab of your user profile and you'll get a free +100 Meta rep (since you have >200 SO rep).

Answer (score 6):

No common standard? But as far as i know, the syntax of keywords is still always the same, isn't it? Words beginning with "\" are keywords. % are comments. To highlight these words accordingly would already be enough to make it much more readable. At least it should be possible to turn off the "regular" code highlighting. 
This example shows most of the problems:

```
%----Header----
...
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,style=altlist]{glossaries}

\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
pdfborder=0 0 0,
pdfpagelabels,
plainpages=false,
linktocpage=false,
pdfcreator={LaTeX}]{hyperref}
...
%Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{glos:twitter}{name=Twitter,
description={Mikroblogging-Service.}}

%----Main document----
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
This text is a normal glossary item: \gls{glos:twitter}.
This text should also link to the glossary item: \glslink{glos:twitter}{Link to Twitter} 
but there is no link
...
\printglossary
\end{document}
```