# LaTeX-specific syntax highlighting for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, syntax-highlighting, latex

Yes, I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56258/stackoverflow-should-have-latex-syntax-highlighting) about adding [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) syntax highlighting to the general purpose system on Stack Overflow proper. However, there are now at least three sites ([MathOverflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/about), and [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about)), where LaTeX is probably going to be the only language inside all those code blocks. So this is a request for a single-language syntax highlighting system just for LaTeX to be used on those sites.

---

Shreevatsar posted on meta.tex.stackexchange:
A toy example of something that ought to be highlighted correctly:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This is # not a comment
  \item This is % a comment
\end{enumerate}
```

A good syntax highlighter would recognize which lines are comments, and also probably do something with 'begin', 'end' and 'item' (as the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting) does).

(It seems a weaker version of this has been asked before as [Syntax Highlighting Hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints/), and there's even a somewhat simple hack that is [not implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41419/allow-class-attribute-for-code-tag/41434#41434). Irrespective of all that history, consider this another request for TeX-specific syntax highlighting on this website, not necessarily using any of the more general solutions.)

Comment: Note that Mathoverflow, at least, doesn't often have occasion for syntax-highlighting LaTeX code: instead the requirement is to typeset mathematics *using* TeX-style input, which is handled by jsmath. It's mainly tex.stackexchange, as well Stack Overflow and SuperUser, that need syntax highlighting for LaTeX. Despite all the history, I remain foolishly optimistic that the overlords here will listen to requests and implement it. :-)

Comment: Original question on meta.tex.stackexchange.com: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10/syntax-highlighting

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You are right that the non-tex sites will probably have little reason to use TeX in code blocks. What I meant was that if these sites ever do use code, there is a very high chance that it will be in LaTeX. If people think it detracts from the point, I am open to changing it.

Comment: This should be opened on the per-site meta for discussion, not here. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/where-should-we-post-feature-requests-for-stack-exchange-betas/58449#58449

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I didn't ask this question here and wouldn't have thought of it, but this is really a cross-site request for several Stack Exchange sites, not just one. (But it's a variant of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56258/stackoverflow-should-have-latex-syntax-highlighting).)

Comment: @Jeff: What if I rephrased the question to ask something more general: Can stackexchange sites have language-specific syntax highlighting if they expect only one language to be used?

Answer (score 5):

It would be ridiculous if lex syntax highlighting wasn't supported in a website whose only objective is to ask lex questions.

Comment: but then, it’s ridiculous that syntax highlighting still doesn’t work for all common languages on a site whose only objective is to ask general-purpose programming questions (Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Konrad: this is for technical reasons; it's impossible to correctly detect the programming language if you want to support several.

Comment: is asking for "lex" syntax highlighting on a question about "TeX" syntax highlighting intentional? I mean, it seem to point out the issue that the team faces in this. The current highlighting engine is heuristic and simply takes advantage of the similarity of many popular languages. But in the Stack Exchange era, *every* site will, reasonable, want correct highlighting for their language.

Comment: No, it’s *not* for technical reasons, it’s purely ideological. Prettify *does* support explicitly specifying the language. There’s no  (technical) reason not to allow this on Stack Overflow. The Stack Overflow Markdown implementation simply filters the relevant attribute.